# Excel-VBA Check If Sheet Contains

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I need to compare order number and if it matches on the outstanding sheet, add it to sheet 1.

For example.

```
sheet 1 contains:
OR1545  
OR1687  
OR898   
OR0142
```

The outstanding sheet contains.

```
OR898   6684D8D
OR0142  6544D
OR0142  8489DD
OR0142  897EEA
```

So the sheet1 will check the outstanding sheet and add the items to the OR column.
If there are more then 1 item to goes to the next column.

So the final output on sheet 1 would be:

```
OR0142  615     6544D   897EEA
OR898   645DD   6684D8D
```

Comment: And you need VBA to do this? I think this can be done using formulas.

Comment: The only reason I want to do it in VBA is because I use it on lots of sheets. I am open to both solutions though

Comment: We are talking of how many rows here? That will help decide which way to go. :)

Comment: @L42 varies from 10,000 to 50,000 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is using the formula:

`=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=$A2,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5)),COLUMN(A$1)))),"")`

Above is an `Array Formula` entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in `Cell C2` and copied to the remaining cells of interest.
Assuming your data is organized like below:

**Sheet1:**
[image: Sheet1]

**Outstanding sheet:**
[image: Sheet2]

**Here is the code:**

```
Sub test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim myfilters
Dim myfilter
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set ws1 = Sheet3
Set ws2 = Sheet2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ws1
    Set rng1 = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    myfilters = rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 1)
End With

With ws2
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Set rng2 = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each myfilter In myfilters
        rng2.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myfilter
        rng2.Offset(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        rng1.Find(myfilter, rng1(1)).Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, , , True
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    Next
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Not tested though.
So test it in a duplicate data for safety.
Hope this helps.